# How to update list in list in dynamodb using boto3

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a table in dynamodb which looks like this

```
{"category": "geographie",
  "words": [
    {
      "hilfestellung": [
        "Hauptstadt von Belgien",
        "Die Schokolade ist berühmt"
      ],
      "user": [
        "useridxyz"
      ],
      "word": "brüssel"
    },
    {
      "hilfestellung": [
        "Hauptstadt von Deutschland",
        "Die Fußballmannschaft heisst Hertha BSC"
      ],
      "user": [],
      "word": "berlin"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I append a new userId in the list `user` where the `word` equals brüssel using python and boto3? I found out how to append a new list_item in boto3, but couldn't find out how to append an item in a list of a list.

Comment: Is this question actuall? This does Not Look like an dynamodb tree...